# Create two object Highslide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highslide

I faced with problem. I create two objects in highslide at the same time, but one of them don't activated (I can't close or move him). Below I write example:

```js
hs.graphicsDir = 'http://highslide.com/highslide/graphics/';
hs.outlineType = 'rounded-white';

function paint(id){
    
 var element = document.getElementById('highslide-html_' + id);
 var frame = hs.htmlExpand(element, { contentId: 'highslide-html_' + id });
 return frame;
}

paint("id1");
paint("id2");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://highslide.com/highslide/highslide.js.php?full=true"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://highslide.com/highslide/highslide.css" />


<div class="highslide-html-content highslide-move" id="highslide-html_id1">
 <div class="highslide-header">
  <ul>
   <li class="highslide-close">
    <a href="#" onclick="return hs.close(this)">Close</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="highslide-body">
  Panel 1
 </div>
    <div class="highslide-footer">
        <div>
            <span class="highslide-resize" title="Resize">
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="highslide-html-content highslide-move" id="highslide-html_id2">
 <div class="highslide-header">
  <ul>
   <li class="highslide-close">
    <a href="#" onclick="return hs.close(this)">Close</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="highslide-body">
  Panel 2
 </div>
    <div class="highslide-footer">
        <div>
            <span class="highslide-resize" title="Resize">
                <span></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It doesn't work only when I create two objects at once. If I place paint(...) into the onclick handler, I can create any number of objects, and they will all be interactive.

Maybe anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohh, I found a solution.

Necessary add `hs.allowSimultaneousLoading = true;`